# Firebase real-time database remove deletes everything instead of a single item

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I can add and retrieve items just fine but when I **delete**, it **removes the whole node**, programs instead.

I tried putting the key directly at the **`this.programListRef.remove(key manually put here);`**  but still got the same results.

I then checked my `programListRef`, nothing seemed wrong too.

Here is the code

```
export class ProgramService {
    //list variables
    programListRef: AngularFireList<Program>;
  programList: Observable<Program[]>;

    //object variables
    programObjRef: AngularFireObject<Program>;
  programObj: Observable<Program>;

  constructor(private afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.programListRef = afDB.list('programs');

    //use snapshot changes.map to store key
    this.programList = this.programListRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => 
        changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      )
    );
   }

   getProgramList() {
    return this.programList;
   }

   getProgramObj(id:string) {
     this.programObjRef = this.afDB.object('programs/'+id);
     this.programObj = this.programObjRef.valueChanges();
     return this.programObj;
   }
   addProgramObj(programObj:Program) {
    this.programListRef.push(programObj);
   }
   updateProgramObj(id:string, programObj:Program){
    this.programListRef.update(id, programObj);
  }


//The problematic code
   deleteProgramObj(id:string){
    this.programListRef.remove(id);
  }

}
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated, thank you for reading!

Answer (score 2):

Try using update.

```
deleteProgramObj(id:string){
    this.programListRef.update({id: null});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! This might be the temporary fix for the "I tried putting the key directly at the this.programListRef.remove(key manually put here); but still got the same results."

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Key was undefined which made it delete the whole node.

And so it seems that the error was on my side.
on my HTML page, I used a ngFor that listed out the objects and I used a different name for the let obj of programList on the click function of delete.
Which made it pass Undefined that prompted it to delete the whole node due to remove() method deletes everything if id is not specified.

AngularFire Docs says:

"**Deleting the entire list**

If you **omit** the key parameter from .remove() it **deletes** the entire list.

```
const itemsRef = db.list('items');
itemsRef.remove();"
```

Comment: what about your remark `this.programListRef.remove(key manually put here)`? and still same result ?

Comment: That...I fiddled with the code a bit and somehow it worked(changed names of var and methods). Which would mean that this might still be unresolved. I really don't know why it behaved that way